# Processing multiple files through application in r

Tags: r

I'm processing files through an application using R. The application requires a simple inputfile, outputfilename specification as parameters. Using the below code, this works fine.

```
input <- "\"7374.txt\"" 
output <- "\"7374_cleaned.txt\""

system2("DataCleaner", args = c(input, output))
```

However I wish to process a folder of .txt files, rather then have to do each one individually. If i had access to the source code i would simply alter the application to accept a folder rather then an individual file, but unfortunately i don't. Is it possible to somehow do this in R? I had tried starting to create a loop,

```
input <-  dir(pattern=".txt")
```

but i don't know how i could insert a vector in as an argument without the regex included as part of that? Also i would then need to be able to paste '_cleaned' on to the end of the outputfile names? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, I can't test it because I don't have your `DataCleaner` program but how about this...

```
# make some files
dir.create('folder')
x = sapply(seq_along(1:5), function(f) {t = tempfile(tmpdir = 'folder', fileext = '.txt'); file.create(t); t})

# find the files
inputfiles = list.files(path = 'folder', pattern = 'txt', full.names = T)
# remove the extension
base = tools::file_path_sans_ext(inputfiles)
# make the output file names
outputfiles = paste0(base, '_cleaned.txt')

mysystem <- function(input, output) {
    system2('DataCleaner', args = c(input, output))
}

lapply(seq_along(1:length(inputfiles)), function(f) mysystem(inputfiles[f], outputfiles[f]))
```

It uses `lapply` to iterate over all the members of the input and output files and calls the system2 function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @awchisholm .The inputfiles/ outputfiles seem correct, and there are no error messages produced. However, the application fails to execute and there are no output files produced. The final line of code produces the following on the console;  [[1]] [1] 127 [[2]] [1] 127 [[3]] [1] 127                                                                                                                      
i'm not sure what 127 refers too. The application simply extracts 'correct' lines in a .txt, and saves these lines to a new file.

Comment: It's impossible to run because we don't have your environment. Is it Mac, Linux or Windows for example? Suggest you make a simple program that takes the first argument and simply makes a copy using the name of the second argument. If this gives trouble because of the `system2` command, I would suggest raising another question to keep to the one question, one answer rule.

Comment: It's a windows environment. That's a fair point, I'll do that. I'll see if i can get the source code as well in the mean time.

Comment: I can confirm that the code does indeed work @awchisholm. The application i was executing had somehow become renamed, and once corrected worked fine